# Align bottom for bootstrap not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and need to vertically align one column to the bottom. It's just not working. Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <div><span id='Name' class="response"></span> <span id='Country' class="response"></span></div>
    <div id="vidspace"></div>
    </div><!--end  col-md-8--></!--end>
    <div class="col-md-4 vbottom">
    <table id="personInfo">
    <tr><td>Age:</td><td id='Age' class="response"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Neighborhood:</td><td id='Neighborhood' class="response"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Distance from Home:</td><td id='fromHome' class="response"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Occupation:</td><td id='Occupation' class="response"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div><!--end  col-md-4--></!--end>
    </div><!--end row --></!--end>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#person_wrapper {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 10%;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;

    height: auto;
}

.vbottom {
    display: table-cell!important;
    vertical-align: bottom!important;
}
```

Comment: what did you mean by "align one column to the bottom"? You want the whole `.vbottom` div to stick to the bottom of the page?

Comment: No, I just want the stuff in col-md-4 vbottom to be vertically aligned at the bottom of that div.

Comment: I think you're misusing the vertical-align css feature. I'm also not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish by vertical-aligning a div that contains a table. Please use this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ycY4xvJHNoLOVXUV13vu?p=preview) as a starting point, and let us know the overall goal, or an example of where you've seen it done before.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom value for verticle-align aligns the element with the bottom element. So it technically is at the bottom already.

If you want to move it down your window, one way would be:

```
.vbottom {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:50%;
}
```

If you could clarify what you want, I'd be able to give you a better answer.